# Table trigger after update on single column

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am quite new to using triggers in SQL and cannot seem to find any tutorials on the subject that kinda goes the same direction as my wish.

I have the following table:

```
id  int(11) AI PK
user_id int(11)
academy_id  int(11)
module_id   int(11)
module_type_id  int(11)
team_id int(11)
score   int(11)
medal_id    int(11) PK
timestamp   datetime
possible_correct    int(11)
user_correct    int(11)
```

Now my goal is to create an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger on this table so that when the update is done the `score` column is recalculated with the following (`possible_correct / user_correct` )

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the same table using trigger `after update`, you need to it `before update` and set the values something as

```
delimiter //
create trigger `your_trigger_name` before update on `your_table_name`
for each row
begin
 if new.possible_correct > 0 and new.user_correct > 0 then
   set new.score = new.possible_correct / new.user_correct ;
 end if ;
end;//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: The value that i am typically updating is one of the values that is within the calculation will this work then??

Comment: Yes it will work as long as both the values are greater than `0`. I have added the condition to avoid the divisible by 0 issue in case you have 0 set for the user_correct